# python .write() method changes my XML output

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml, elementtree

when i try to edit my XML file using xml.etree.celement library and I then try to write the change to a new XML file, there a changes to my XML file.

I need to make changes to the XML file and then write an exact replica just with the changes i made to the text.  I have tried to use standards such as c14n and use the correct encodeing and xml declaration but still no luck.

encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True

The file still has minor changes such as:

in original DOC:

```
<remote-name>&#10;glossary_name        </remote-name>
```

and in new doc I have:

```
<remote-name>
glossary_name        </remote-name>
```

How can I make them EXACTLY the same with just the minor change

I use this little script:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import os
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import tkFileDialog
from lxml import etree as tt

## Grab the Particular file to convert xml
xmldoc = tt.parse(newfile)
root  = xmldoc.getroot()
##loop through to convert the images to the correct Path
##finds the intro dashboard and converts the image
for dashboard in root.iter('dashboard'):
    if dashboard.get('name') == "Intro":

        ##Loops through the zones within a specified dashboard
        for zone in list(dashboard.iter('zone')):
            if zone.get('id') == ('88'):
                zone.set('param', 'customerFiles/Image/Intro - Top.png')        
    else:
        continue

xmldoc.write_c14n('output.xml')
#os.rename('output.xml',"output.twb")
```

Comment: sorry initially it looks like:  <remote-name>&#10;
glossary_name        </remote-name>  

in new doc it looks like:

<remote-name>
glossary_name        </remote-name>